# Emojis not being rendered properly on mobile browsers in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, emoji, html-renderer

If i put a string like this one 'Can you solve the quiz? #AI got puzzled! 30 for 5 each!To win  FL &❤️ & RT @binary_x2⃣ Fill in the blank & tag 2 friends!' in Text Widget it gets rendered properly on any browser.

However, if i use

```
  return String.fromCharCode(emojiCode!);
```

with html renderer on iOS Safari it shows this
[broken emojis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvYhh.png).

It still renders properly on desktop browsers, but it breaks on android browsers aswell. I know a fix with Noto fonts by using Canvaskit renderer, but i would like to make this work with html renderer.
Any ideas?

First i was using Canvaskit renderer, but im trying to move to html due to initial loading time. However, i am unable to get Emojis to display properly on mobile browsers, while on desktop everything works as expected.

Comment: I think you need `Custom Emoji Font` - like this: https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji You can include the emoji font in your app's assets and specify it in your TextStyle for any Text widget displaying emojis. If you're using emojis in the middle of text, consider using RichText with TextSpan, where you can specify different styles (and thus different fonts) for different parts of the text.

Comment: @UtmostCreator it is 22 mb

Comment: Is it too much? you can have a look at this one: https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji but it is still almost 19mb. I think maybe you can check their requests or FAQ or ask them if it is possible to reduce the size of it, as i suppose because it is multi-platform its size is more than it actually would be.

Comment: But why should i need to download a font when an emoji inputed directly shows properly, and the one got from String.fromCharCode doesn't work (only on Android though). Setting fontFamily to '' fixed the issue on iOS

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to create a textspan with two different style.

```
    TextSpan _buildTextSpan(String label) {
  // Stores all the TextSpans that will be combined into the final one
  final children = <TextSpan>[];

  // Converts the label to a sequence of Unicode code points (runes)
  final runes = label.runes;

  for (int i = 0; i < runes.length;) {
    int current = runes.elementAt(i);

    // Check if the current rune represents an emoji
    final isEmoji = current > 255;
    // function to determine if a rune should be considered part
    // of the current emoji/text chunk based on emoji boundaries
    final shouldBreak = isEmoji ? (x) => x <= 255 : (x) => x > 255;
    List<int> chunk = <int>[];

    while (!shouldBreak(current)) {
      chunk.add(current);
      if (++i >= runes.length) break;
      current = runes.elementAt(i);
    }

    final span = String.fromCharCodes(chunk);

    children.add(TextSpan(
      text: span,
      style: isEmoji ? GoogleFonts.notoColorEmoji() : GoogleFonts.inter(),
    ));
  }

  return TextSpan(children: children);
}
```